# How to set correctly the initial conditions with Infinity?

Tags: differential-equations

I have two functions given by the following differential equation system:

```
eqn={
 T''[t] == (2 m)/(2 R[t] (R[t] - 2 m)) T'[t] R'[t],
 R''[t] == (2 m (R[t] - 2 m))/R[t]^3 T'[t] T'[t] - (2 m)/(2 R[t] (R[t] - 2 m)) R'[t]^2
 }
```

This must be solved with `NDSolve` since they are too complicated, the initial conditions are `R'[0]==0,R[0]==Infinity` and `T[0]==0,T'[0]==1`

My question is about the `Infinity` in the initial conditions: how to correctly impose it?

In the above equations `m=10`.

Comment: What's the value of m?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I am sorry I forgot to write it: `m=10`

Comment: The start conditions `eqn /. t -> 0 /. {R'[0] -> 0, R[0] -> inf, T[0] -> 0, T'[0] -> 0} (*{(T^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] == 0, (R^\[Prime]\[Prime])[0] == 0}*)` indicate  that `R[t]=inf,T[t]==0` solves your equations!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann so the particle never moves. what if I set the IC `T'[0]==1`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I am sorry the initial condition is indeed `T'[0]=1`: it is the derivative of the coordinate time wrt the proper time in a Schwarzschild spacetime and at infinity it reduces to a Minkowsky spacetime so that `T'[0]=1`

Comment: You can't numerically solve from the initial condition R[0]= infinity. (It will take infinite proper time to reach any finite R).

Comment: The only way to numerically handle boundary conditions with infinities like this, is the re-write your problem in terms of a transformation of the variables that re-scales them to finite numbers. For example, the substitution `y[t] == LogisticSigmoid[R[t]]` will map the b.c. `R[0] == Infinity` to `y[0] == 1`;