# How to find T[R]?

Tags: differential-equations

This is a second question about the system:

```
eqn={T''[t] == (2 m)/(2 R[t] (R[t] - 2 m)) T'[t] R'[t],   R''[t] == (2 m (R[t] - 2 m))/R[t]^3 T'[t] T'[t] - (2 m)/(2 R[t] (R[t] - 2 m)) R'[t]^2}
```

This must be solved with `NDSolve` since they are too complicated, the initial conditions are `R'[0]==0,R[0]==Infinity` and `T[0]==0,T'[0]==0`

In my [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/228328/8822) I asked how to correctly set the initial conditions. Here I ask: once I have found `T[t]` and `R[t]` how do I find `T[R]`?

Comment: What do you mean by "finding it"? You can plot it with `ParametricPlot`. Similarly, you can `Table[{T[t], R[t]}, {t, start, end, step}]`. Since these are tivial, I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I must use `T[R]` in other computations, not just plot it

Comment: So use the `Table` I showed. Apply `Interpolation` to it if you want a function as output.